# is there a cross-platform unicode string class that I can use both on Win32 and MacOSX systems?

Tags: c++, unicode, locale, uppercase, unicode-string

Also I need locale aware case conversion. .NET do this very well. Do us C++ programmers have to wait 100 years for such thing ? I am aware of the ICU library but it's 20MB and I can't even get to link my code with it... All in all I want to end this nightmare..

Comment: The .NET code that does this was written in C++.  Nobody can help you if you just rant and not document your link problem.

Comment: 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall icu_46::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(unsigned short const *)" (__imp_??0UnicodeString@icu_46@@QAE@PBG@Z) referenced in function _main


this is the error I get although I link all the .lib files in ICU library. I use VC++10 . Also tried compiling ICU with VC++10 and linking to those output files but no luck... I need to build my code both on Windows and MacOSX

Comment: please don't rant, it doesn't make for good question material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use the API provided by the operating system. Windows has NLS API that deals with locale specific string comparison and case conversion.

Standalone Unicode Libraries are ICU and IConv. Both require some time to learn. The data file is also quite large - expect to carry > 10M data files to support most languages.

BTW, your link error is typically caused by the fact that you specified a static library but the imported function has dllimport attribute which specifies a DLL. By default ICU header files declare dllimport on its APIs. You need to define a macro before including the ICU header.

Comment: If you only need case mapping, you can trim ICU down quite substantially. It's large because of what's covered.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your solution for link error please?

Comment: this answer was helpful in explaining the issue, is there a way of directly calling the code in ICU without dllimport if static linking?

Answer (score 2):

- [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) is a cross platform unicode library, a part of [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/), and part of the POSIX.1-2001 standard. It's also available on Mac and Windows.
- [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf8) is a character encoding that is backwards compatible with ASCII.
- [C strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string) are null terminated byte arrays that can hold ASCII and UTF-8.

That's all you need. Encode/decode to UTF-16 and UCS-32 or what have you when required to interface with legacy operating systems.

Comment: It's a bit tough to describe Windows as inferior just because it's suffering from having supported Unicode before UTF-8 was invented!

Comment: @David Heffernan: We meet again :). I've updated the answer to be more PC.